# Will this run in Async parallel and is this good coding practice?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to run these Tasks in parallel. But I have the feeling that i'm not doing this correctly.

I tried looking on the internet and I saw many people say that using .Result should be avoided, but I don't know how I could do that in this case.

```
 var B =  SomeTaskA().
                ContinueWith(result => SomeTaskB(result.Result)).Result; //Task B depends on task A
var D =  SomeTaskC()    //Task C doesn't depend on Task A or B, so i want to run this parallel.
                .ContinueWith(result => SomeTaskD(result.Result)).Result;

            ObjectB bvalue = await B;
            ObjectD dvalue = await D;
```

I expect it to run in parallel but i'm not sure if that actually happens.

Comment: Seeing only a reference to a task, and not how the task was created, nor its payload, it's impossible to tell how it will run. You might choose to read ["There is no thread"](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) before pursuing this further.

Comment: These are not real tasks. I just want Task A and C to run at the same time and to run B as soon as A is done and D as soon as C is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you most likely want is to run them *concurrently*, not in parallel. Concurrency is doing more than one thing at a time; parallel is splitting up work among multiple threads.

First, don't use `ContinueWith`; use `async`/`await` instead:

```
async Task AThenB()
{
  var a = await SomeTaskA();
  return await SomeTaskB(a);
}

async Task CThenD()
{
  var c = await SomeTaskC();
  return await SomeTaskD(c);
}
```

Once you have defined these methods, you can use `await Task.WhenAll` for asynchronous concurrency:

```
var bTask = AThenB();
var dTask = CThenD();
await Task.WhenAll(bTask, dTask);
ObjectB bValue = await bTask;
ObjectD dValue = await dTask;
```

Comment: Stephen im reading your answer and im not understanding something, if you are already using await Task.WhenAll, why do you await again the result of the task?

Comment: @nalnpir `bTask` and `dTask` are tasks (in a known, completed state after `Task.All` is completed), not the results of the tasks. They need unwrapping to access the values they contain. You might choose `bTask.Result` etc, or just `await` the task in order to unwrap the result. Given that `Task.Result` can lead to some pretty toxic bugs when misused, it's always advisable to stick to `await` if possible. Frankly, I'd be happy to see `Task.Result` removed from the `Task` API. It's rarely used correctly.

Comment: @nalnpir: I do it just because `await` is the natural way to consume tasks. What @spender said. :)

Comment: @spender, Task.Result is useful for joining an async Task back to the current thread thereby evaluating it as if it were synchronous again. It is necessary functionality even if it is often misused. Obviously, you'd never want to use it on during the execution of the UI thread.

Comment: @Steph Cleary, the await keyword might consume a task, but it also spawns a task--it must be inside an async context.

Comment: @Rhaokiel: Sync-over-async is an antipattern. Even if you are forced to do it, you would want to use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` and not `.Result`, in order to avoid `AggregateException` wrappers.

Comment: @spender Would the result of the answer be the same if Task.WhenAll was left out? Since the tasks are awaited after that anyways?

Comment: @Zoidbergseasharp: Almost. If `bTask` fails much sooner than `dTask`, then the `Task.WhenAll` will only raise that exception after `dTask` completes. I do find the explicit `Task.WhenAll` more clearly indicates the intent of the code, so I generally leave it in.